# Double try_files to solve the nginx's "No input file specified" issue

Tags: nginx, wordpress, wordpress-mu

I am following the nginx's wiki (http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress) to setup my wordpress

```
   location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

By using the above lines, when a static file which is not found it will redirect to `index.php` of wordpress, that is okay but..

**Problem: When I request an non-existence php script, e.g. http://www.example.com/foo.php, nginx will give me**

```
No input file specified
```

I want nginx to return 404 instead of the above message, so in the **main fcgi config**, I add the 2nd `try_files`

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files  $uri =404;

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    ...
}
```

And this worked, but I am looking if there are any better way to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, that's the normal way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Using try_files in your PHP location only works so long as the server with that specific nginx instance also has the PHP code. This is certainly not always the case and therefore will not always work.

What you can do is use [fastcgi_intercept_errors](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule#fastcgi_intercept_errors) to have nginx intercept errors from your PHP backend and then process them with its own error_page error handler. This allows you a custom handler defined in nginx.